# I can't get output from a function in F#

Tags: .net, function, f#, return-value

I am trying to make this function work (it is bigger, but I tried to find a mistake)

```ml
open System
open System.Text
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let GetField (line:string) (num_skip:int) : int =
    let b = 5
    b
let main() =
    let mutable str1: string = "qwerty"
    let a = GetField str1 1
main()
```

but this error appears:

> error FS0588: Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.

if I use parenthesis:

```ml
let a = (GetField str1 1)
```

I will get the same error here.

I tried at first this:

```ml
open System
open System.Text
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let GetField (line:string) (num_skip:int) : int =
    let b = 5
    b
let main() =
    let mutable str1: string = "qwerty"
    GetField str1 1
main()
```

and it worked but threw a warning:

> warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'int'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.
> warning FS0988: Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run

Comment: After `let a = GetField str1 1`, you need to be doing something more, to end the function. If you don't want to do anything more in particular, you can end the function with a line with just `()` in it - an empty parenthesis, or the only possible value of type `unit` to be precise. In the second case, `main` calls `GetField str1 1` at the end, but doesn't use the result, likely since the call to `main` at the bottom indicates to the compiler that `main` should not return anything. To fix that, write `GetField str1 1 |> ignore` to just throw away the result, since you're not using it.

Comment: If your intention is to have a main function that is an entry point and returns a program exit code, then look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point#explicit-entry-point). Scroll up on that page to read about what you've got now.

Comment: @Bent Tranberg Thank you, my functions finally work